# Data goes missing when tables go from intraday to regular tables

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase and BigQuery to make a dashboard. I found the discrepancy once the data transferred to the "regular events table" from the "intraday table".

[image]

I've been saving the intraday table for the last three days to compare the values when the data is transferred to the regular event table. I found out there is some problem while transferring the events data to the regular table as some of the rows were removed while transferring the data.

Does anyone know what needs to be done here?

Comment: Contact support?

Comment: Yes, he told me it's not in the purview of support.

Comment: You'll need to edit your question to provide more specific details. There's just not enough detail provided, to help others help you. Also, please see [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - it's very important to provide properly-formatted text, not images of text.